# Accessing Compojure query string

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm trying to pull a value out of the url query string however I can return what I believe is a map, however when i use the below code, it doesn't process it as expected.  Can anyone advise how I access specific values in the returned querystring datastructure?

http://localhost:8080/remservice?foo=bar

```
(defroutes my-routes
  (GET "/" [] (layout (home-view)))
  (GET "/remservice*" {params :query-params} (str (:parameter params))))
```

Comment: Here are two questions. Does this function take a parameter? What is GET? Here is why I'm asking. You should be able to extract what you need from params, but where is params?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your handler in `compojure.handler/api` or `compojure.handler/site` to add appropriate middleware to gain access to `:query-params`. This used to happen automagically in `defroutes`, but no longer does. Once you do that, the `{params :query-params}` destructuring form will cause `params` to be bound to `{"foo" "bar"}` when you hit `/remservice` with `foo=bar` as the query string.

(Or you could add in `wrap-params` etc. by hand -- these reside in various `ring.middleware.*` namespaces; see [the code of `compojure.handler`](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/blob/a5784f2f888ae54e6b6681398cc0029023564e85/src/compojure/handler.clj) (link to the relevant file in Compojure 1.0.1) for their names.)

E.g.

```
(defroutes my-routes
  (GET "/remservice*" {params :query-params}
       (str params)))

(def handler (-> my-routes compojure.handler/api))

; now pass #'handler to run-jetty (if that's what you're using)
```

If you now hit `http://localhost:8080/remservice?foo=bar`, you should see `{"foo" "bar"}` -- the textual representation of your query string parsed into a Clojure map.

Comment: Ok I've got it returning a map, however i can't seem to access in the individual entries, e.g. (:foo params) or (get params foo) or (map :foo params) does not return anything.  I think thats my main confusion around this map structure returned.

Comment: That's because the keys are kept in string form -- you'll need to use `(get params "foo")`. Alternatively, you can use `:params` instead of `:query-params` -- Compojure's `api` adds in the `wrap-keyword-params` middleware, so the `:params` map is "keyified" -- but note that `:params` includes both types of parameters (the other being form parameters; query parameters override form parameters in the `:params` map).

Comment: How do you do something like this: /users/123?sort=desc

I have params passed to the vector.

Answer (score 1):

In the default app for compojure 1.2.0, the querystring middleware seems included by default. You can inspect the request as such.

```
(GET "/" request (str request))
```

It should have a lot of stuff, including the `params` key.

```
{ . . .  :params {:key1 "value1" :key2 "value2} . . . }
```

As such, you can include a standard Clojure destructuring form to access the query parameters in your response.

```
(GET "/" {params :params} (str params))
```

Your page should then look like the following.

```
{"key1" "value1", "key2" "value2"}
```

As noted in the comment by Michal above, however, the keys are converted to strings and if you'd like to access them you need to use the get function rather than the more convenient symbol lookups.

```
(GET "/" {params :params} (get params "key1"))

;;the response body should be "value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `compojure 1.6.1` HTTP-request-destructuring works for me in a such way:

1. add `[ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]` in `:dependencies` in `project.clj` (because `compojure.handler` namespace was deprecated since 1.2 in favor of the `[ring-defaults]`)
2. add `[ring.middleware.defaults :refer :all]` in `:require` in `your.routes.namespace`
3. add `(def site (wrap-defaults app site-defaults))` in `your.routes.namespace`, where `app` is declared via `(defroutes app ...`
4. add `:ring {:handler your.routes.namespace/site}` in `project.clj`

Answer (score -1):

I had luck in compojure 1.1.5 not needing a wrapper and being able to use the `:as` directive

```
(GET "/tweet/:folder/:detail" [folder detail :as req]
  (twitter-controller/tweet folder detail (-> req :params :oauth_verifier))
```